substitution to evaluate $\iint_{R} (x-3y)dA $ using Jacobian
Evaluate $ \iint_R (x-3y) dA $  where R is the triangular region with vertices $(0, 0), (2, 1), (1, 2)$
I tried  substitution $u = \frac{y}{x}, v = x+y  $ but it couldn't make a region.
Let me know how can I substitute for it and some tips for substitution.

Try $(u,v) = (2x-y,2y-x)$. Then the three points are mapped to $(0,0)$, $(3,0)$, and $(0,3)$ respectively. This is a right angled triangle aligned with the axes, so the integrals can be separated more nicely.

How did you get that substitution? I want to know how can I choose good substitution

I was trying to make sure that the two non-origin points lie on the axes. And I wanted to use linear transformations so that the final region is also a triangle.
